# Azure insert script not working

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have two tables in an Azure database and I am trying to add a script where the user can insert data into one table field every time something is entered into the table Transactions. The tables are in different schemas but in the same database.

When a row is entered in the database Transactions, I need to check if the user account from the row is in the table 'UserTable', fetch the record from UserTable and then replace the data in the field 'Balance'

I have tried the following script but nothing happens. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

```
function insert(item, user, request) 
{

var userTable = tables.getTable('UserTable');
var total = item.Amount + userTable.Balance;
var data = {
        Balance: total,
    };

if(userTable.UserAccount === item.UserAccount)
{
userTable.insert(data);
}

request.execute();
}
```

Comment: What framework is that code working against? It's impossible to help you without knowing that. Also, please include your script in your question and not a link to it. That will increase the odds of somebody helping you.

Comment: I am using a C# windows app with mobile services to enter data into the table. The insert script is in the Azure scripts. Not sure if I am explaining myself well though.

Comment: Why not use a Trigger for this purpose? You can use an Instead Of trigger to replace values before they are saved.

Comment: I want to replace the value in another table though - because the sale amount will be entered in one table and I want to update the total sales in another table. Can this still be done?

Answer (score 1):

The `userTable` object which you get from `tables.getTable` gives you a reference to the table object. It doesn't have a `Balance` or a `UserAccount` property which you're trying to access. What you need to do is to first **query** the userTable, then with the result make the updates. The script below should do something similar to what you need.

```
function insert(item, user, request) 
{
    var userTable = tables.getTable('UserTable');
    userTable.where({ UserAccount: item.UserAccount }).read({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.length === 0) {
                // new user. can either return an error, or add
                // new entry. Will add a new entry here.
                userTable.insert({ Balance: item.Amount }, {
                    success: function() {
                        // insert the transaction
                        request.execute();
                    }
                });
            } else if (results.length === 1) {
                // Found it. will update the result
                var userAccount = results[0];
                var total = userAccount.Balance + item.Amount;
                userAccount.Balance = total;
                userTable.update(userAccount, {
                    success: function() {
                        // insert the transaction
                        request.execute();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Something is wrong
                request.respond(
                    statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    { error: 'multiple users with same account' });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When I used this I got this error:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Error: Internal Server Error

Comment: Please check the logs on the portal, maybe there is some information there about what is going on.

Comment: Ok the error I have is this: Error in script '/table/UserTransactions.insert.js'. Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'tc.UserTable'.  Now the table UserTable is not in the schema tc but in the schema dbo. Is there a way I can refer to the table in the other schema? I tried writing dbo.UserTable but I got another error.

Comment: If you created the table via the Mobile Services portal (or via the Command-Line Interface), then it should work. It looks like this is not your case (your table was created directly in the database). In this case, you'll need to talk to the database directly (using the `mssql` object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj554212.aspx), instead of the `tables` global). The logic should be the same, but you'll be sending SQL commands instead of calling the table methods.

Comment: Ok I have changed the code to use mysql object. I am not getting this error though: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'UserTable'. Is there somewhere I can change the select and insert permissions from?

Comment: Ok I have managed to add user permissions using SQL Management Studio and GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[UserTable] TO guestUser. Now my issue is with the reading of the values in the table. The value I want to read was a float but I had to change it to nvarchar to be able to enter the data using this code: var bal = results[0]; var total = bal.value + item.Amount; This enters the value as so: [object Object]0.85. Now I want the 0.85 only. Also, the addition is not being performed perhaps since the reader is not reading the value as a float value. I tried using parseFloat(bal.value) but I got an error